# Datastax AMI on AWS EC2 mount failure

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra-2.0

I have followed the latest directions on ( http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installAMIConnect.html)
and the opscenterd is not runnning.
I think this is because of a disk mount problem in the installation:  ( ~/datastax_ami/ami.log )

```
[EXEC] 08/09/14-21:36:58 sudo service opscenterd restart:
 * Restarting Cassandra cluster manager opscenterd
   ...done.

[INFO] Skipping initial configurations.
[INFO] AMI Type: Community
[ERROR] 08/10/14-05:33:24 sudo mount -a:
mount: special device /dev/xvdb1 does not exist
```

Comment: I had not properly set up the security groups. Once that was done the installation went perfectly!

Comment: Do you know what exactly was wrong with the security groups? I followed this doc http://datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installAMISecurityGroup.html and double-check, but I still get the mounting error after restarting cluster.